# Bootstrap ui typeahead async not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-promise

I am using bootstrap ui typeahead. So when the user types I want to load data asynchronously. So I created a factory which has a http req to get the data.

```
angular.module('customers').controller('CustomersController', ['$scope', function($scope){
        $scope.searchUser = function(val) {
            searchUser.getUsers(val, $scope.searchField, $scope.searchPattern, $scope.displayCount).then(function(response){
                    // console.log(response.data
                    return response.data
                });
            }
    }]).factory('searchUser', ['$http', function($http) {
            return {
                getUsers: function(val, callback){
                    return $http({
                        url: '/search/user/' + val,
                        method: 'GET'
                    })
                }
            }
        }]);
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selectedUser" placeholder="Search User" typeahead="user.firstname for user in searchUser($viewValue) | filter:{firstname:$viewValue}" typeahead-on-select="onSearchItemSelect($item, $model, $label)" class="form-control">
```

But I keep on getting the below error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>   at ui-bootstrap-tpls.js:3186
>       at m.promise.then.u (angular.js:11319)
>       at m.promise.then.u (angular.js:11319)
>       at angular.js:11405
>       at h.a.$get.h.$eval (angular.js:12412)
>       at h.a.$get.h.$digest (angular.js:12224)
>       at h.a.$get.h.$apply (angular.js:12516)
>       at HTMLInputElement.l (angular.js:16632)
>       at HTMLInputElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (jquery.js:4409)
>       at HTMLInputElement.jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4095)

I almost tried all the answers accepted on stackoverflow. But I get the same error.

**EDIT**
FYI: I tried changing the name of the function(since the function and the factory names are the same) and it didn't help. If I console log the response.data in the function I can see the returned output, but it is not returned to the type ahead.

Actually, the below code works without creating a factory. But the problem is, when I go to a different page which loads the same controller, this promise automatically keeps on gets the requests resulting in page freeze.

```
$scope.searchUser = function(val) {
    return $http.get('/search/user/' + val)
    .then(function(response){
        return response.data
    })
}
```

Comment: did you really wrap `searchUser.getUsers` inside `searchUser` method of controller & `limitToFilter` returning an array?

Comment: @PankajParkar Yes. that's what I've done

Comment: could you add more code..question is unclear now

Comment: @PankajParkar I've added the codes. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: I asked for `limitToFilter` what it does?

Comment: @PankajParkar I just use it to limit the number of results shown in the typeahead. I tried removing that and gives the same error. I have edited the code now.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `limitTo` filter in this way, you should first inject $filter dependency to controller and then use `limitTo` filter

> Should be like
>
> `$filter('limitTo')(input, limit, begin)`

**Code**

```
.controller('CustomersController', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.searchUser = function(val) {
      return $http.get('/search/user/' + val)
        .then(function(response) {
          return $filter('limitTo')(response.data, 10);
        });
    }
}]).
```

Comment: Even if I try this code i get the same error. Also I tried removing the limitTo filter and results with the same error.

Comment: This is what I have mentioned in my last edit. This code will work, but the searchUser function automatically runs in all the views that loads CustomersController and keeps on sending request to the server resulting in page freezing. But the searchUser is a new function that is not used else where.

Comment: @Pradeep could you try `user.firstname for user in searchUser($viewValue) | filter:{firstname:$viewValue}| limitTo: 10`

Comment: Still shows the same error. I tried an 'alert' before the "return response.data" in the controller but the error appears even before I close the alert box. Whereas if I put an alert before calling the factory it waits for the alert box to close and then reports the error. So am I doing something wrong with the promise?

Comment: @Pradeep could you create a plunkr for the same?